# ОШИБКА - Не удалось развернуть приложение на контекстном пути

Tags: java, java-ee, netbeans, jsf

До вчерашнего дня, все работало как часы.
Потом, просто перестало работать, пытаюсь просто создать проект с jsf, выдает данную ошибку...  Server - Tomcat 10, Jdk - 17
В интернете решения нет. Не работали также и другие проекты, но это исправилось отключением, через config tomcat, но если отключить и попробовать запустить, пишет тоже-самое еще и +не стартовало. В server.xml, нечего править)))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
19-Jan-2022 17:26:04.337 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/WebApplication3]
19-Jan-2022 17:26:04.384 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication3.xml]
19-Jan-2022 17:26:04.387 WARNING [http-nio-9090-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/WebApplication3] in deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication3.xml] has been ignored
19-Jan-2022 17:26:04.761 SEVERE [http-nio-9090-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication3.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:693)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1780)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1592)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1027)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:358)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebApplication3]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2516)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:516)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:662)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5168)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1444)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
        ... 60 more
19-Jan-2022 17:26:04.763 INFO [http-nio-9090-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication3.xml] has finished in [378] ms
```

Comment: Там же написано `see the server log for details`. Каким образом мы можем посмотреть логи Вашего сервера, скажите пожалуйста?

Comment: @Sergey добавил

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849452/classnotfoundexception-with-servletcontextlistener
смотреть как минимум все ответы, за которые имеется хоть один голос.

Comment: @Сергей В остальных проектах все работает, данные ответы - не помогли!!! Проблема возникает именно когда создают проект с jsf

Comment: Прожект maven? может `pom.xml` покажите? Или проверьте зависимости о всех `javaee-web-api` (или `jakartaee-web-api`). Думаю, они должны быть `provided`. Может `jsf-api` и/или `servlet-api` прописаны отдельной строкой? В общем проверить какие библиотеки откуда грузятся. Если есть библиотека на сервере приложений, то почти наверняка её и надо использовать, указав в pom.xml для соответствующей зависимости scope provided.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо вам большое за помощь!!! Переустановил, сработала.

Comment: @Sergey Добрый, опять возникает данная проблема, дело в том что, я ничего не делал с проектом, просто создаешь обычный проект в netbeans в чистом виде и он не работает. То есть я ничего не менял в коде, ничего не обновлял и т.д.

Comment: Даже не знаю чем ещё помочь. Сам использую netbeans. Но давно перешёл на прожекты в формате maven, И tomcat никогда не применял. Только wildfly и payara. Но Ваша проблема чётко указана - не может найти класс javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener. Но это класс точно должен быть у любого сервера javaee. Иначе на фига нужен такой сервер? Возможно этот класс замещается библиотекой, которую тянет за собой Ваша сборка, и у сервера происходит какой-то сбой в понимании того, откуда грузить этот класс.